# why google mock returns error no matching function for call

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

In the code bellow I get the error on EXPECTED_CALL(..)

"no matching function for call to 'dia::security::SecurityLevelMock::gmock_acceptEvent()'"

which is weird since I have the method implemented.

Any hint would be appreciated.

```
class SecurityLevelMock
{
public:
   virtual ~SecurityLevelMock( void ) {}
   MOCK_METHOD3( acceptEvent, resulttype( statemachine::stateevent event, void* pArg, resulttype initialErrorCode ) ); /*implemented by this class*/
   MOCK_METHOD2( acceptEvent, resulttype( statemachine::stateevent event, void* pArg ) );                              /*implemented by this class*/

};
  

class SecurityLevel : public SecurityLevelMock, public std::enable_shared_from_this<SecurityLevel>
{
//...code
}

TEST_F( SecurityLevelAccess_UT, mytest )
{
  auto security_level_access_obj = std::make_shared<SecurityLevelAccess>( "val1", p1 , p2, "val2" );
  //...
  EXPECT_CALL(*(std::shared_ptr<dia::security::SecurityLevelMock>)security_level_access_obj, acceptEvent( ) ).Times( 1 );

}
//file.h
class SecurityLevelAccess : public security::SecurityLevel
{
//code
}
```

Comment: I Solved it by : making a dynamic cast of object security_level_access_obj  to SecurityLevelMock and then 
   EXPECT_CALL( *sec_level_mock, acceptEvent( 0,0,0 ) ).Times( 1 ); I have no idea why now works

Comment: Do you inherit a production class from a mock class? Shouldn't this be the opposite - you create mocks by inheriting from a "target" class?